# Can i write my own firmware for a scanning device in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, barcode-scanner, firmware

i was wondering if it was possible to write my own firmware that will run on a device im making. This device is very similar to the price portable price checkers you see in grocery stores. it scans the barcode which returns an id number.  More information about my device and about the big project im working on can be found here:

[My Idea For A New Type Of WCP (Wireless Connection Protocol)](http://shorttext.com/I6ZMoz)

I'd like to write this firmware in VB.net because im Very Familiar with it, however if another language would be better please specify which one and where i should start.

An example of what i want the scanning firmware to be like is the iphone/ipod touch application called Qrafter. it allows you to scan any QR code and depending on what its value is, act accordingly.

**Firmware Spec Requirements:**

Essentially, i want this firmware to get the value of the QR code that the scanner reads, and compare the value to the ID that is stored as a variable in the firmware itself. when i make more devices ill assign each one a unique device ID that corresponds with a QR code to match.

Comment: It is 99.99% guaranteed that this device doesn't boot Windows.  99.9% guaranteed that you can't get the programming documentation for the device.  So no.

Comment: look at the .NET Micro Framework (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/netmf/default.aspx)

Comment: You can of course, write whatever you want. It won't load and won't run, though.

Comment: Suffice it to say that you're not a security expert/cryptographer, and most likely (not being cruel, just stating the facts) will never be a security expert/cryptographer. This means that by [Schneier's Law](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html), you can come up with whatever "secure" protocol you want, and that most anyone with experience in the field will be able to drive a tank through.

Comment: i simply want this program to interprent the QR code and compare its value with a pre-defined number and send the results to my computer (the reciever)

Comment: if i can get the code that is used to scan and interpret the qr code, do you think i could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device you are making surely is using some type of microcontroller. You will need to write the firmware in the language the microcontroller supports.

If you are still in the <s>vapor</s>planning stages, you can start looking at [Netduino](http://netduino.com/) microcontrollers that uses the .NET Micro Framework

Some blog posts on Netduino:

- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNETMicroFrameworkHardwareForSoftwarePeople.aspx
- http://10rem.net/blog/2010/09/02/first-experiences-with-netduino-and-the-net-micro-framework

Comment: Netduino and the Fez range are fantastic devices. http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/compare/

Comment: this is the answer ive been looking for and i really appreciate it!

Comment: i have a quick question if have another second, do you know what kind of firmware and/or hardware that a standard price checker uses? i mean the ones you see at super markets or large stores. thats almost exactly what im trying to achive (with a few differences)

Comment: My advice is to use a PocketPC integrated barcode scanner. The only thing you have to do is make a program in the PocketPC. http://www.barcodesinc.com/cats/portable-data-terminals/pocketpc.htm